# Understanding a passage involving total and partial derivatives

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, hamilton-equations

I'm reading [Michael Betancourt's "A Conceptual Introduction to Hamiltonian Monte Carlo"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.02434). However my question is just about a particular passage involving total and partial derivatives.

On page 25, he defines:

> Because of the decomposition of the joint density, the Hamiltonian,
> $$H(q,p)\equiv-\log\pi(q,p),$$
> itself decomposes into two terms,
> \begin{align*}
> H(q,p) & \equiv-\log\pi(p\mid q) -\log\pi(q)\\
> & \equiv K(p,q) +V(q).
> \end{align*}

and then goes on to define *Hamilton's Equations*:

> \begin{align*}
> \frac{\mathrm{d}q}{\mathrm{d}t} & =+\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}=\frac{\partial K}{\partial p}\\
> \frac{\mathrm{d}p}{\mathrm{d}t} &=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial q}=-\frac{\partial K}{\partial q}-\frac{\partial V}{\partial q}.
> \end{align*}

I don't follow the leftmost equality in each of the two lines above. How does he go from the total derivative $\frac{\text{d} q}{\text{d} t}$ to $+\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}$? From $\frac{\text{d} p}{\text{d} t}$ to $-\frac{\partial H}{\partial q}$?

Comment: The first equality follows from Hamilton's equation. (Actually, it's just Hamilton's equations of motion.)

Comment: I know, but what is the justification for that equality? I don't see how it follows from the definition of H.

Comment: I think the logic goes like this. You start with a function $H(p, q)$. The function has level curves which you would like to call energy levels. You want to study motions on a fixed energy level.  The easiest way is to define equations of motions where each trajectory lies on a fixed energy level. One of the easiest systems of equations that satisfies your need is Hamilton's equations. So, you work them.

Comment: In short, you choose the time derivative of $q$ to equal $\partial H/\partial p$ and the time derivative of $p$ to equal $-\partial H/\partial q$.

Comment: Ah, so it is a definition of the derivative rather than an equality obtained as a consequence of something else. Got it, thanks. If you write that as an answer I can make it the chosen answer.

Comment: Also, why the $+$ for the derivative of $q$ and $-$ for the derivative of $p$?

Comment: It is just a convention.